# winforms select part of text in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am lookingfor method to select part of text in Item.subItemsCollection in listview e.g.
text of

```
     item.subitem[0].text = "thats text";
```

but i want to highlight (chage color) only for letters "ats" in "thats" word. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you want.  Check out the DrawItem event on the ListView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is certainly no easy way to do this, but you can use someone else's work :)

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView) -- an open source wrapper around a .NET ListView control -- has a `HighlightTextRenderer` which will do exactly that. [Read about it here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#highlighttextrenderer).

Here, it is highlighting "er":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) - it contains Item Highlighting feature which does just this (can be combined with seaching by typing and search filtering):

[image]