# How to make part of ListViewItem text to be bold?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, text, text-styling

I have a ListView in Details mode, and I'd like to have some of its items' text in bold (for highlighting where it finds some substring in the item text).

So something like this:

Somefilename/**boldText**/etc

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just like @KlausByskovHoffmann asked, is it windows or web?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that... its WinForm app

Comment: Have you ever drawn text before using GDI? Because that's what you're going to have to do.

Comment: See answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191254/winforms-select-part-of-text-in-listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is going to be difficult because you're going to have to `OwnerDraw` your `ListView` first by setting that property to `true`. Now that you've done that you're going to need to implement `DrawColumnHeader` and place this line in it:

```
e.DrawDefault = true;
```

Next you'll need to implement the following code, either in `DrawItem` or `DrawSubItem` depending on which area it exists in. ***Keep in mind the code I'm giving you isn't fully complete because it's not parsing the string or anything and further you still need to implement drawing a selected item now because your drawing the text on your own.***

```
var boldFont = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
var location = new PointF(e.Bounds.Location.X, e.Bounds.Location.Y);

e.Graphics.DrawString("Somefilename/", this.Font, Brushes.Black, location);
var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString("Somefilename/", this.Font);

location.X += size.Width;
e.Graphics.DrawString("boldText", boldFont, Brushes.Black, location);
size = e.Graphics.MeasureString("boldText", boldFont);

location.X += size.Width;
e.Graphics.DrawString("/etc", this.Font, Brushes.Black, location);
```

Another thing to note is that you'll have to play with the offsets a little because some fonts have margins and bolded fonts take up more room.

***If the `Item` is not a `SubItem` then just implement the `e.DrawDefault = true;` for the `DrawSubItem` event - and vica versa if the item is a `SubItem` then implement that line for `DrawItem`.***

Comment: Thank you :) this is what i was looking for. But i still have 1 problem. When i draw my text it looks weird in meaning of the letter lines are wider, with kind of green outline. It look blurry if you know what i mean :)

Comment: Instead of using `Brushes.Black` you could try using `SystemBrushes.WindowText`. But that's a shot in the dark because I wasn't experiencing that.

Comment: It didn't help :( here is screen of that (top text is obviously wrong drawed, but as soon as I select this item it goes right and since that everything is ok) http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/7375/screenuoa.png

Comment: Normal ListView is rendered using GDI which tends to be clearer. DrawString() uses GDI+ which has lots of advantages but looks different. Before doing any text renderering, make sure you tell GDI+ to use ClearType rendering: g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

Comment: Thanks Grammarian, totaly worked for me :) but i had to use System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit instead of ClearTypeGridFit which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to override OnPaint. Try these links:

[Make portion of a Label's Text to be styled bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063263/make-portion-of-a-labels-text-to-be-styled-bold)

[Custom ListView in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604704/custom-listview-in-winforms)

But, the listview is not painted by the .net framework and is only supported. So, even if you override the OnPaint, it might not be called. So you might have to override your listview control as well.

Comment: OnPaint will definitely not help you. You'll have to a lot of work with a ListView to do something this complicated. Look at ObjectListView for an example.

Comment: That is correct - I placed in a **very** partial implementation of how to draw the text the OP wanted, but there is a lot more work to do. @Grammarian, if you have more to add to my post please feel free.

Comment: True, the .UseItemStyleForSubItems = false has to be set for each item. This is the most suitable answer in my opinion.