# Can I bold a word in listviewitem subitems?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can I do something like this in listview??
1 | foo | **bar**12 | x |
2 | foo | 32**bar** | y |

I want to bold particular word 'bar' in this case.
Is it possible in the listview, or is there any alternative to make it work?

Comment: By drawing it yourself in an ownerdraw `ListView`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090727/how-to-make-part-of-listviewitem-text-to-be-bold?rq=1) looks like exactly what you're asking to do

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful to you...

```
    Dim item1 As New ListViewItem
    item1.Text = "Item 1 BOLD"
    item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False      'Set this to FALSE to allow changing the subitem font. It is TRUE by default.
    item1.Font = New Font(ListView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    item1.SubItems.Add("Sub Item Normal")
    item1.SubItems(1).Font = New Font(ListView1.Font, FontStyle.Regular)

    ListView1.Items.Add(item1)
```

Comment: OP is looking for a way to set the font of a sub item partially. What you shared is setting the font for the whole text of sub item.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this post. I guess this won't change just one word. It'll bold the whole cell.